# How to apply a function to each row of a matrix with arguments from the corresponding row of another matrix

Tags: r

For example, there are two matrices:

```
A <- matrix(1:10,nrow=2)
B <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

If I want to extract some elements of each row of A and the corresponding row of B provides the index range of A's elements, is there a simple way to do this? In the above example, the first row of A is c(1,3,5,7,9) and I want to get the 1st to 3rd elements (as indicated in the first row of B, c(1,3)), i.e., c(1,3,5). For the second row of A, I want to get the 2nd to 4th elements, i.e., c(4,6,8). So the result that I expect is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 5

[[2]]
[1] 4 6 8
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `lapply` operating on the row indices:

```
lapply(seq(nrow(B)), function(idx) A[idx,B[idx,1]:B[idx,2]])
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 6 8
```

Comment: That is an interesting use of 'lapply' function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just for fun you can use this fancy approach `lapply(seq(ncol(B)), function(i) A[i, Reduce(seq, B[i,])])`

Comment: If I need to deal with higher-dimension matrix, how could I do it? For example, if `dim(A)` is c(2,3,5) and `dim(B)` is c(2,3,2) and the calculation is on the third dimension, how could I use this `lapply` method?

Comment: @ZNN you'd need to modify it to loop through all possible indices in the two dimensions instead of just `seq(nrow(B))`; looping over rows of `expand.grid(seq(dim(B)[1]), seq(dim(B)[2]))` would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate over the rows of the matrices:

```
res <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
    res[[i]] <- A[i, B[i,1]:B[i,2]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have confined myself in using 'apply' functions for solution. Your solution is simple and direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Map` function (which is similar to `mapply` without simplification in this case)

```
Map(function(i,a,b) A[i, a:b], seq.int(ncol(B)), B[,1], B[,2])
```

This may extend to more dimensions more easily.